# API WebExtensions Firefox : Chrome is undefined

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm actually trying to use the WebExtensions API on my nightly Firefox (dated today). I developed a chrome web extensions before and it works like a charm on Chrome.

I managed to install my extension. I followed this link to do so : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Packaging_and_installation

The extension is correctly installed, but I can't seem to make things work.

I constantly have the following error "chrome is undefined". Did I miss something ? (I noticed that the examples given here : https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples show how to use the extensions, and "chrome.*" is used with no kind of problem.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Did you add the extra information to your manifest file? Like target app gecko etc?

Comment: Yes, I Added it. I unfortunately have the same issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: •the desired behavior, •a specific problem or error *and* •the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Are you using `chrome` in content script or background script? There is a difference between those two.

Comment: Thanks Martin Zhai, actually that was the problem. I didn't answer the question but if you want, I can upvote yours if you answer my post !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe import the chrome functions like
`const {Cc,Ci,Cu} = require("chrome");` ?

Comment: This is a different `chrome` then the user is expecting. Thanks very much though for trying to help out.